# Three.js globe - Make countries clickable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I am able to render and animate rotation for a 3D earth using three.js by adding a world map image texture onto a sphere using the tutorial at the following link. I intend to make the countries in the globe clickable. Ie., whenever user clicks on any country, the country's border should be highlighted a pop over should list it's name. I imagine I will need to use d3.js to load a GeoJSON of countries and add it as a mesh in three.js. But I have no clue of achieving that through code.

Can anyone help please?

http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/09/creating-webgl-earth-with-threejs.html?m=1

Comment: Lol the article you linked is super dumb - there is no ambient lighting in space. For the problem itself - I would just add invisible texture to the globe with a different color for each country, and try to query a color value when user clicks. Having a map between the color value as an id and country name it could be possible to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google service to figure out which country is clicked:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lon + "&sensor=false";
```

See http://jsdo.it/makc/19UWi for working example. Not helpful with country borders, though. Alternatively, use the approach from http://makc.github.io/three.js/map2globe/demo.html where each country is separate object.